# Cypress - install it on empty project

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to install cypress on an empty project. However, cypress is not installed in the package.js file and cypress is not included on the project. How can I make it work? I cannot install cypress as part of the development project, so i am trying to create a separate test automation project with cypress.

Comment: hi can you share screenshot of it if there is any error ? also try this tutorial as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dArfrRnyp8A

Comment: Have you read https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#System-requirements?

Answer (score 4):

Steps to install cypress:

Step 1: Create your project folder, go inside the folder from the terminal using `cd folder_path/folder_name` and run `npm init`. This will create your `package.json` file inside your project folder. You can do this in a sperate project or create some folder in your development project and do it there as well.

Step 2: Now, Run the command `npm install cypress --save-dev`. This will add the cypress as a dev dependency inside your `package.json` file. Once you have successfully installed this, you should see one more file `package-lock.json` and an folder `node_modules` being created

Step 3: Run the command `node_modules/.bin/cypress open` or `node_modules/.bin/cypress run` to run cypress.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add --save or --save-dev to save it to package.json file. eg: `npm install cypress --save`. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used npm install cypress --save-dev to install cypress and even though it didn't include cypress in the package.js / project solution.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you install Cypress into your dev project, but I see you can't do that.

Go to `https://www.cypress.io`, middle of the page is **Download now**.

After downloading, unzip to a folder, open bash or cmd prompt in that folder and type **Cypress**.

You get some warnings about installing into your project being preferred, but it works fine.

There's a **To get started...** box on the runner. Choose the same folder, and Cypress will set up the testing folder structure

```
/cypress
  /integration
    /examples       -- lots of sample tests here
  /support
  /plugins
  /fixtures
  etc
```