# Is it possible to have a standalone Cypress test repository, separate from the front end application?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, web-frontend, ui-testing

1. Is it possible to have a standalone Cypress test repository, separate from the front end application? The reason behind this is that our website itself has different components which are placed in separate Github repositories. I would want to write Cypress tests for the entire website. Although I could write tests specific to repo, I would imagine having to rewrite helpers etc. which leads to my second question.
2. Is it possible to share helpers across repositories or have a centralized repository for some helpers which I could reuse across projects.
   There might be a better way to do this which I'm unaware of.

Comment: No problem, see this answer for the centralized repository implementation [Cypress - install it on empty project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65701150/14903560)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a central repository is fine. Or you can piggyback on the source code for the primary component, whatever that is. The Cypress code and tests are completely independent from the app's code.

Comment: Thanks, that helps I'm going to give that a try

Comment: So creating a central repository/standalone cypress project was fine. But is there a way to access the commands.js file of one project from another project? Or any any other support file across projects?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, sorry. I don't see why you couldn't specify the full path on the import line of `index.js`, but surely there's a cleaner way.